# Compile time hash - confusion on template deduction order

Tags: c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I have found this piece of code in other topic

```
template<size_t N, size_t I = 0>
struct hash_calc
{
  static constexpr size_t apply(const char(&s)[N])
  {
    return  (hash_calc < N, I + 1 >::apply(s) ^ s[I]) * 16777619u;
  };
};

template<size_t N>
struct hash_calc<N, N>
{
  static constexpr size_t apply(const char(&s)[N])
  {
    return 2166136261u;
  };
};

template<size_t N>
constexpr size_t hash(const char(&s)[N])
{
  return hash_calc<N>::apply(s);
}
```

First of all, I am totally confused why it does not end being an infinite recursive call? From what I understand, first `hash_calc<N, I>` is always going to call itself, what causes it to break at the `hash_calc<N, N>` when `I` reaches `N`? The template instantiation for `hash_calc<N, I>` does not fail when `N == I`.
Second - i tried to copy paste the `hash_calc<N, N>` struct over `hash_calc<N, I>` which causes compile error `error: 'hash_calc' is not a class template struct hash_calc<N, N>`. Why is that?!

Edit:
The modified code below does not compile under msvc nor gcc. I have just put one template over other. What happened?

```
template<size_t N>
struct hash_calc<N, N>
{
    static constexpr size_t apply(const char(&s)[N])
    {
        return 2166136261u;
    };
};

template<size_t N, size_t I = 0>
struct hash_calc
{
  static constexpr size_t apply(const char(&s)[N])
  {
    return  (hash_calc < N, I + 1 >::apply(s) ^ s[I]) * 16777619u;
  };
};

template<size_t N>
constexpr size_t hashq(const char(&s)[N])
{
  return hash_calc<N>::apply(s);
}
```

Comment: Template instantiation process is going to use partial specialization over the primary template whenever possible. That's the whole point of providing specializations, after all - so that they get used when they match the actual arguments. You seem to believe that the primary template must fail to instantiate before the specialization is considered - that's not the case.

Comment: *" i tried to copy paste the `hash_calc<N, N>` struct over `hash_calc<N, I>`"* I don't understand what you mean by that. If you have a piece of code that produces a compiler error, then show that piece of code and the exact text of the compiler error.

Comment: I have modified first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am totally confused why it does not end being an infinite recursive call?

So let's look at it, step by step.

`hashq<N>(const char(&s)[N])` calls `hash_calc<N>::apply(s);`.

That's:

```
template<size_t N, size_t I = 0>
struct hash_calc
{
  static constexpr size_t apply(const char(&s)[N])
  {
    return  (hash_calc < N, I + 1 >::apply(s) ^ s[I]) * 16777619u;
  };
};
```

with `I==0`.
Now `hash_calc < N, I + 1 >::apply(s)` is called, with `I==1`, this goes on until `I==N`. That's when

```
template<size_t N>
struct hash_calc<N, N>
{
    static constexpr size_t apply(const char(&s)[N])
    {
        return 2166136261u;
    };
};
```

is called. And the recursion ends.

> Why is that?!

```
template<size_t N, size_t I = 0>
struct hash_calc
{
  static constexpr size_t apply(const char(&s)[N])
  {
    return  (hash_calc < N, I + 1 >::apply(s) ^ s[I]) * 16777619u;
  };
};
```

is the more general case, it handles any pair of `<N,I>`, whereas

```
template<size_t N>
struct hash_calc<N, N>
{
    static constexpr size_t apply(const char(&s)[N])
    {
        return 2166136261u;
    };
};
```

is its specialisation, it can only handle the case of `<N,N>`.
The compiler first needs the general case and then the specialiation.

Comment: Oh, i did not notice the specialization at first look... I am used to the `template<>` syntax, the `template<size_t N>` is a specialisation indeed but looks nothing like `<>`, thats what confused me.
Thanks a lot!